# What features should I look for in a scope for a .308?

Tags: hunting, guns

I've Googled this a lot over the last couple of days, but it feels like most of the answers are aimed at target shooting. I live in South Africa, and we do allot of hunting in the bushveld as well as long distance shooting in the Karoo. I'm looking for a good all round scope that can accommodate short distances (80m) as well as long (300m).

**[Update]**

I ended up buying a [Fortex PST Viper 6-24x50 ERB-1 MOA SFP](http://www.vortexoptics.com/product/vortex-viper-pst-6-24x50-riflescope-with-ebr-1-moa-reticle), which is a true pleasure to use!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some characteristics that I can give you for a good scope, selecting the individual one will be up to you

- Variable Magnification for both short and long distances.
- Nitrogen filled to prevent fogging.
- Has a sunshade to prevent glare.
- Smaller MOA on the turrets for sighting it in. (1/8 [MOA](http://nssf.org/video/facts/MOA.cfm) increments)
- Illuminated reticle for low light
- A larger main tube (30mm vs 1 inch) will be brighter
- If you get a mildot or a [MOA](http://nssf.org/video/facts/MOA.cfm) scope, make sure its a [first-focal plane](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20549/what-are-the-differences-between-and-the-pros-and-cons-of-first-vs-second-focal) scope.
- Fits in your budget.